# Get Class for inner class

Tags: java, reflection

```
package test.abc;

public abstract class Base {
 ...
 public static class ChildInner extends Base {
  ...
 }
}
```

When I call `Class.forName("test.abc.Base.ChildInner")` I get `ClassNotFoundException`. What's going wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried `test.abc.Base$ChildInner` ?

The inner class name is fully qualified by the outer class name, and the inner/outer distinction by the `$` symbol.

Note that this is how the compiler names and saves those inner classes when compiling. You'll see them in your filesystem amongst your classes.

Comment: Indeed.  Inner classes were a language hack introduced in Java 1.1, and we're stuck with these bits of random weirdness even now.